# AngularJS directives: turning jQuery nav-scroll into directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm having some trouble turning my jQuery into pure angularjs in a directive.. as far as I understand it should be working but then again I've only ever made one directive before.

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong? Nothing happens with the directive.

Here is the jQuery:

```
$(".page-header-fixed .navbar.scroll-hide").mouseover(function () {
    $(".page-header-fixed .navbar.scroll-hide").removeClass("closed");

    return setTimeout((function () {
        return $(".page-header-fixed .navbar.scroll-hide").css({
            overflow: "visible"
        });
    }), 150);
});

$(function () {
    var delta, lastScrollTop;
    lastScrollTop = 0;
    delta = 50;

    return $(window).scroll(function(event) {
        var st;

        st = $(this).scrollTop();

        if (Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta) {
            return;
        }

        if (st > lastScrollTop) {
            $('.page-header-fixed .navbar.scroll-hide').addClass("closed");
        } else {
            $('.page-header-fixed .navbar.scroll-hide').removeClass("closed");
        }

        return lastScrollTop = st;
    });
});
```

Here is my directive:

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.directives')
        .directive('navScroll', navScroll);

    function navScroll() {
        return function (element) {
            var windowEl = angular.element($window);
            var delta = 50;
            var lastScrollTip = 0;

            element.bind('mouseover', function () {
                element.removeClass('closed');

                return $timeout((function () {
                    return element.css({
                        overflow: 'visible'
                    });
                }), 150);
            });

            windowEl.on('scroll', function () {
                var st = windowEl.scrollTop();

                if (Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta) {
                    return;
                }

                if (st > lastScrollTop)
                    element.addClass('closed');
                else
                    element.removeClass('closed');

                return lastScrollTop = st;
            });
        };
    }

})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a few syntax errors and misspelled variables, in addition to the fact that the `navScroll` function has to return an object. You also didn't inject the `$window` and `$timeout` dependencies. I've rewritten your example below:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app.directives').directive('navScroll', ['$window', '$timeout', function($window, $timeout){
        return {
          restrict: 'A',
          link: function (scope, element) {
              var windowEl = angular.element($window);
              var delta = 50;
              var lastScrollTop = 0;

              element.bind('mouseover', function () {
                  element.removeClass('closed');

                  $timeout(function () {
                      element.css({
                          overflow: 'visible'
                      });
                  }, 150);
              });

              windowEl.on('scroll', function () {
                  var st = windowEl.scrollTop();

                  if (Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta) {
                      return;
                  }

                  if (st > lastScrollTop)
                      element.addClass('closed');
                  else
                      element.removeClass('closed');

                  lastScrollTop = st;
              });
          }
        };
    }]);
})();
```

Afterwards you can apply it to an element by adding the `nav-scroll` attribute to it:

```
<div nav-scroll></div>
```

Comment: Hmm I already have the nav-scroll attribute and I tried your additional code but doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Ah wow I can't believe I forgot to inject dependencies lol. That seems to have solved it as well as the return statement error at the bottom. Plus the typo. Thanks! BTW, no need to restrict 'A', if nothing is specified it already defaults to 'A', which is what is being used in this case. But doesn't hurt either :D